# Ubuntu with only CLI image... No more GUI

Tags: command-line, iso

I'm looking for ubuntu image which has only cli. I want install it on my windows pc through VM Box. I don't like switching from GUI to CLI or changing grub files.

Where I can get pure cli ubuntu os image?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you are asking for is the Ubuntu Server

http://www.ubuntu.com/server

However, if you do want cli only, I'm inclined to recommend you to Debian.